# facing coding error when want to train the model in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, training-data

the code I used was:

```
!python3 object_detection/model_main.py \
--pipeline_config_path=/gdrive/My\ Drive/object_detection/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config \
--model_dir=training/
```

and the errors I faced were:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 109, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 71, in main
    FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples))
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 617, in create_estimator_and_inputs
    pipeline_config_path, config_override=config_override)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 103, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 122, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 84, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:/gdrive/My Drive/object_detection/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config; No such file or directory
```

I have checked so many time that the path is already correct and connected, but don't know why still occur this error, please help!

Comment: Try to copy the file in a colab folder before using it.

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply, but I not understand what to do after I copy the file? is it copy the config file?

Comment: instead of using a path for files that are inside your drive (`gdrive/My Drive/...`) copy the files you need in a folder inside colab (`my_folder/needed_files`) and use that. if you mount drive in colab is not like an external drive so a lot of things won't work. But if you copy the files you will have everything in the colab hdd and maybe will work.

Comment: Is it you mean I should upload all the related files to colab instead of mount drive to colab? I will try it first! thank you very much for the help, I am newbie in this field so I may still need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do `!cp /path_inside_drive /path_outside_drive`

Comment: I had used the method you said, but then there is another error occur which is as below:  google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2:1 : '%%writefile {model_pipline}': Expected identifier or number, got %.